# JSON - line height in SharePoint Tiles/Gallery view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, json-formatting

I have created a SharePoint Online list and added some JSON to the Tiles/Gallery view.

One of the columns is a "multiple lines of text" type of column. The column is displaying text fine in the Tiles/Gallery view, however the line spacing is too big.

Is there any property I can use to change this? Surprisingly I wasn't able to find anything online.

Comment: Plain text column or rich text column? Spacing between two lines or spacing between two words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to change the spacing between two lines of text, you can manage it using `line-height` CSS property.

For example:

Default spacing in gallery view for Description column:

[image]

Spacing in gallery view for Description column after adding `line-height` styling:

[image]

**Note**: You have to add `line-height` CSS property to element styling for respective text column in JSON:

```
"line-height": "100%"
```

You can try using different values instead of 100% as per your requirements.

---

Similarly, you can manage the spacing between two words using `word-spacing` property like:

```
"word-spacing": "10px"
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed, works great! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!